# View Excel property on Linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel

I have some excel files and need to determine the original creator. On a PC I can check the properties of the excel file, but I want to know if there is something on a linux computer to do this.

Update: I found this `exiftool` which can read and display the metadata of both .xls and .xlsx excel files. It is available in major linux distribution repos.

Comment: How about installing Excel on Linux under Wine? Then do anything like you do in excel on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file` utility. On a terminal, just type in `file <filename>` and it will show you all details about that file. The "Author" tag will also be included. Example ::

> [root@xxxxx ~]$file MOM_Date\ Template.xls 
>  MOM_Date Template.xls:
>   Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows,
>   Version 6.1, Code page: 1252, **Author: XXXXXX, Last Saved By: XXXXXX**,
>   Create Time/Date: Tue Jan 14 08:18:57 2014, Last Saved Time/Date: Wed
>   Jan 29 09:15:43 2014, Security: 0

Comment: What about xlsx files?

Comment: It will show details for any files. It reads the file header, so it should work just the same with xlsx. Go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: I just tried and it gave only "Microsoft Excel 2007+". But from your answer I found another tool exiftool, which extracted the detailed information. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I guess the tool was unable to read the header for xlsx.